# Print de um valor realizado dentro de uma função bugado

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar um programa que calcule o método da bisecção.

Gostaria que o usuário inserisse a equação desejada e os valores de `a`, `b` e a tolerância, porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que o input da equação seja lida corretamente.

Também não sei se existe uma biblioteca que faça a leitura correta de uma equação. Além disso, criei uma função para me retornar um valor, porém ela está me retorna algo estranho:

```
def funcao_soma(x,y):
    soma = x+y
    return soma

funcao_soma(1,5)
print("A soma foi {}".format(funcao_soma))
```

Ele me retorna:

```
A soma foi <function funcao_soma at 0x000001BC6E8EFF78>
```

Ao invés do valor `6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O resultado da sua função não está sendo salvo em nenhuma variável (linha 5). Deveria ser, por exemplo:

```
resultado = funcao_soma(1,5)
print("A soma foi {}".format(resultado))
```

ou caso não queira usar uma variável intermediária:

```
print("A soma foi {}".format(funcao_soma(1,5)))
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!

Comment: Poderia marcar a resposta como solução, por gentileza?